# DataGridView throws odd errors

Tags: c#, dataset

Simply put i added a new form to my program to see the data directly instead of just manipulating though SQL. well when i add the data set. and it does work in the designer perfectly but when i go to build it it erros out

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error   CS0426  The type name 'Db12DataSet' does not exist in the type 'AllianceERP'    AllianceERP C:\Users\dhelm.ALLMATINC.001\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AllianceERP\AllianceERP\Form2.Designer.cs    230

the line it is referencing is private AllianceERP.Db12DataSet db12DataSet;
with redline under db12DataSet

and i think that the problem is that db12data set isnt in that location but is in another location ? My connection string is right and tested @

```
connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=S:\Documents\2015\Db12.accdb";
```

Where have I gone wrong or is my thinking just off?

Comment: there are actually 5 errors all similar about missing stuff

Comment: so you are saying that you don't know the location of the `.accdb` file also we cannot see any of the code that you are seeing on your end.. do you have a `s:` drive on your local..or remote server..? do a global search and see where the `Db12.accdb` is located and change the Source Path to that location